# Selection Events in ArcObjects using Java

Tags: arcmap, java

I am trying to have an ArcMap addin receive `ISelectionEvents`, but I can't figure out how to register the event handler. I'm using ArcObjects 10.0 for Java. I'm able to catch `IDocumentEvents` as follows:

```
public void init(IApplication app) throws java.io.IOException, com.esri.arcgis.interop.AutomationException{
    super.init(app);
    this.app = app;
    MxDoc doc = (MxDocument) this.app.getDocument();
    doc.addIDocumentEventsListener(new EventCatcher()); // EventCatcher implements IDocumentsEvents and ISelectionEvents
}
```

Any suggestions on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're attempting to create the listener from the Map object, not the Document object, correct? See http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/carto/ISelectionEvents.html

Comment: That is correct.